# como fazer essa variável possuir um valor double #Dart

Tags: variáveis, dart

Se alguém puder me dar uma descrição detalhada, agradeço, sou novo na linguagem

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(){
  var saldo = 100;
   print('   ');
  print('gostaria de sacar dinheiro?: (y/n)');
  String escolha = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (escolha =='y' || escolha =='Y'){
    print('seu saldo é $saldo reais.');
    print('quanto gostaria de sacar?');
    dynamic saque = stdin.readLineSync();
    saque = int.parse(saque);
    if(saque <=saldo){
      print('seu saque de $saque reais foi realizado com sucesso!');
      dynamic saldo_novo = saldo - saque;
      print('novo saldo: $saldo_novo');
    } else{
      print('saldo insuficiente para realizar a operação');
    }
  }
  if (escolha ==  'n' || escolha ==  'N'){
    print('seu saldo não foi alterado');
  }
  print('----------------------');
  print('finalizando programa...');
}
```

> Mensagem de erro
>
> ```
> #0      int._throwFormatException (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:133:5)
> #1      int._parseRadix (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:144:16)
> #2      int._parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:102:12)
> #3      int.parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:65:12)
> #4      main (file:///C:/Users/Allen/Documents/Dart%20things/funcoes.dart:11:17)
> #5      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19)
> #6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você trocar as variáveis do tipo `dynamic` para `double`

Como vai trabalhar com valores reais, tudo será `double`

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  double saldo = 100.0;
  print('   ');
  print('gostaria de sacar dinheiro?: (y/n)');

  String escolha = stdin.readLineSync();

  if (escolha =='y' || escolha =='Y'){
    print('seu saldo é $saldo reais.');
    print('quanto gostaria de sacar?');

    double saque = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

    if(saque <= saldo){
      print('seu saque de $saque reais foi realizado com sucesso!');
      double saldo_novo = saldo - saque;
      print('novo saldo: $saldo_novo');
    } else{
      print('saldo insuficiente para realizar a operação');
    }
  }
  if (escolha ==  'n' || escolha ==  'N'){
    print('seu saldo não foi alterado');
  }
  print('----------------------');
  print('finalizando programa...');
}
```

O tipo `dynamic` permite que sua variável receba qualquer tipo de dado, mas após você setar o primeiro valor a ela, ela passa a aceitar somente o tipo do valor informado.
Por exemplo, se você informar um texto em uma variável `dynamic`, essa passará apenas a aceitar `String`.

Comment: o fato de eu usar dynamics, não ajusta a variável pra mim? ou só me diz que eu posso alterar o valor e o tipo?

Comment: entendi,entendi, pensei que automaticamente o input seria uma string como python, e precisasse converter.

Comment: deu o seguinte erro:  Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'double'., pois acredito que assim como o python, um input é naturalmente uma string

Comment: Ops, desculpe, esqueci dessa questão, vou ajustar a resposta.

Comment: Veja a resposta novamente, não estou podendo testar agora, mas acredito que um `toDouble()` deva resolver.

Comment: fiz um pequeno teste com a importação da biblioteca dart:core , mas o toDouble aparece como indefinido.

Comment: Veja minha resposta, eu coloquei a modificação errado, e depois ajustei pro certo, dessa forma deve dar tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

na realidade, após fazer a seguinte alteração deu erro dizendo que o toDouble não funciona pra strings.

```
import 'dart:core'; //biblioteca do toDouble()
void main(){
  double saldo = 100.0;
  print('   ');
  print('gostaria de sacar dinheiro?: (y/n)');

  String escolha = stdin.readLineSync();

  if (escolha =='y' || escolha =='Y'){
    print('seu saldo é $saldo reais.');
    print('quanto gostaria de sacar?');

    dynamic saque = stdin.readLineSync();
    saque = saque.toDouble();
    if(saque <= saldo){
      print('seu saque de $saque reais foi realizado com sucesso!');
      var saldo_novo = saldo.toDouble() - saque;
      print('novo saldo: $saldo_novo');
    } else{
      print('saldo insuficiente para realizar a operação');
    }
  }
  if (escolha ==  'n' || escolha ==  'N'){
    print('seu saldo não foi alterado');
  }
  print('----------------------');
  print('finalizando programa...');
}
```